How to correctly power an ESP32-H2 board with a battery
I'd like to power my ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board with a 3.7 V, 2000 mAh Li-po battery.
For this I think I must use this pin: Battery-3V3

The above picture is from the Pin Layout section of the documentation.
The battery has a 3.7 V voltage, while the pin is 3.3 V.
The question is: may I connect the battery directly to the ESP32-H2 or is some kind of interface needed?

Suggestion:
Espressif drop the electrical schematic, it appears that VBAT does not go through the regulator, so when voltage is applied to the VBAT pin, the ESP32 will directly receive that voltage from the battery.
ES32-H2-MINI has absolute maximum rating below (3.6V for maximum power supply):

The maximum voltage of 1 cell Li-Po battery is 4.2 V (3.7 is the rated voltage)
So, for your own safety and money, i don't suggest you to directly connect the battery to VBAT pin
If you want to use your Li-Po battery, connect it using a USB-C adapter or use an LDO (5V to 3.3V) regulator.
Reference:
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-h2-mini-1_mini-1u_datasheet_en.pdf

Can't connect a battery with more than 3.6 V to the Battery-3V3 pin
From looking at the documentation for the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board:

The ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 Schematics v1.3 (Applies to boards of and after PW-2024-02-0362) and ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 Schematics v1.2 (Applies to boards before PW-2024-02-0362) show VBAT on J1 pin 12 (Battery-3V3) on the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board is connected to VBAT on the ESP32-H2-MINI-1.

The ESP32-H2-MINI-1/1U Datasheet has a schematic for the ESP32-H2-MINI-1 module. This shows:

VBAT on the module is connected to VBAT on the ESP32-H2 chip.
The zero ohm R2 connects VBAT to the VDD33 net.
The VDD33 net is connected to the VDDA_PMU, VDDPST1, VDDPST2 and VDD3P3 power supply pins on the ESP32-H2 chip.




So, a battery could be connected to the Battery-3V3 pin on the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board to power the board, but the battery voltage on the pin would need to be within the allowed range for the VDD3P3, VBAT, VDDA_PMU,
VDDPST1, VDDPST2 supplies given in the ESP32-H2 datasheet which are:

Absolute maximum of 3.6 V
Recommended Operating Conditions of Min 3.0 V, Typical 3.3 V, Max 3.6 V

I.e. connecting a battery which may have a voltage of more than 3.6 V to the Battery-3V3 pin will damage the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board.
Potential to connect a battery to the 5V0 pin
The schematics of the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board show it contains a SGM2212-3.3XKC3G/TR Low Dropout Linear Regulator to generate 3.3 V from a 5 V input. The datasheet for the regulator shows the following for VDROP, which is the minimum allowed difference between the input voltage and 3.3 V output voltage for different currents:

Therefore, you may be able to connect the battery to the 5V0 pin of the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board, which is connected to the input of the LDO. I'm not sure how much current the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 consumes, and therefore the minimum battery voltage at which the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 would still work.
A possible safety issue with connecting a battery to the 5V0 pin of the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board is that if a USB cable is connected between a USB host and either of the USB-C ports on the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 board is that the 5 V USB VBUS from the host would then attempt to charge the battery. I.e. you need to ensure never connect to the USB-C port while a battery is connected.
